# Problem in Viewing of Files after Downloading

Tags: php, mysql

I created a code to download some PDF file and it works perfectly thru local host but when I uploaded it to the free web host the downloading works fine but when I opened it it says "Error
Failed to load PDF document." Can Anyone tell me what's wrong? and how to fix my problem? link: https://chezanda.000webhostapp.com/metrocombined/

This is the some part of my code from download.php

```
$file = 'media/'.$data['filename'];

if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-Description: '. $data['description']);
    header('Content-Type: '.$data['type']);
header('Content-Disposition: '.$data['disposition'].'; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: '.$data['expires']);
    header('Cache-Control: '.data['cache']);
    header('Pragma: '.$data['pragma']);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
```

and sample data from my database

`newfiles` (`id`, `filename`, `type`, `description`, `disposition`, `expires`, `cache`, `pragma`) VALUES
(1, '02-04b 03a TRAINING CHECKLIST IL.pdf', 'application/octet-stream', 'File Transfer', 'attachment', '0', 'must-revalidate', 'public')

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: There's probably some output in the PDF file that makes it invalid. You could use a simple text editor to view the start of the valid and invalid PDF files, are they the same? I bet there's some error or warning at the beginning of the invalid PDF file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! can you please check your pdf file path?

Comment: Hi Manny, the PDF File Path is Correct, to test the path I tried to remove the file in the path and try to download it and it has error so i guess there's nothing wrong in the path, my only problem is if i downloaded the file over the web it will store to download folder if you are running in Windows and tried to opened it the error comes.

Comment: Script47, no error logs shows in my PDF App